# Update progress bar size with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get a jquery script to evaluate a table cell and divide it by 120 and times that by 100 to get a percentage. This percentage will then update the length of a progress bar.

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var base = $('#stat').val();
        var baseStat = (Math.floor(base) / 120) * 100;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', baseStat + '%');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<td width='5%' id='stat'>20</td>
<td>
    <div class='progress'>
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="120" style="width:0%"></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: You forgot to include a question

Comment: Greg, good to know. What is the problem you're having? If you want to display the result in the HTML, you need to specify that: jQuery `$('#ID of Element To Display To').html()`, or JavaScript `var el = document.getElementById('#ID of Element To Display To')`

Comment: The progress bar is not displaying anything when the script runs. It is able to read the "Math.floor" if I put a static number in where the "base" variable but it does not want to read my variable for "base"

Comment: `$('#stat').val()` should be `$('#stat').text()`. It isn't an input.

Comment: Malk, that makes sense and worked great. I'm new to Jquery so still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` is used to get values from input fields.

Try this:

```
var base = $('#stat').text();
```

EDIT:
`.text()` can be used to get/set text to elements.

See API reference: https://api.jquery.com/text/